# Get length of all elements in array to create a filter in javascript/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of jokes in an array and I want to filter out all the jokes with less than 40 characters. I can get the length of individual jokes in the array for example the 4th one in the array:

```
const filterStuff = jokeComponents[3].props.punchLine.length;
```

but don't know how to get the length of all the jokes in the array so I could set a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code to filter jokes with length less than 40.

```js
const filteredJokes = jokeComponents.filter((joke) => joke.props.punchLine.length < 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const jokeComponents = [{
    "props": {
      "punchLine": "That's a short punchline."
    }
  },
  {
    "props": {
      "punchLine": "This one is way too long and won't show in the filtered resultset."
    }
  },
  {
    "props": {
      "punchLine": "Will also show up in the result."
    }
  },
];

console.log(jokeComponents.filter(joke => joke.props.punchLine.length < 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jokeComponents = ["Punchline one","Punchline two","Punchline three"]; //original jokes array
var jokeComponentsMoreThan40[]; //array of jokes longer than 40
var arrayLength = jokeComponents.length; //size of array
var j = 0;

//loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    //Insert jokes longer than 40 in a new array
    if (jokeComponents[i].length >= 40) {
       jokeComponentsMoreThan40[j] = jokeComponents[i];
       j = j + 1;
     }
}
```